# Add comment below Header

Tags: javascript, html

Hey i got this Code and I would like to add comments below the heading. 
But right now after i click the submit send the header and the button wipes away.
However I would like them to stay so that the text input will be displayed below the button.
Thank you in advance!

```html
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <h1>Add comment below</h1>
    
        
        <label for="vname">Comment:
        <input type="text" id="vname" name="vname">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="addComment()">
        
        <script>
        function addComment()
            {
             var vname = document.getElementById("vname").value;
             document.write(vname);
            }
            </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write`. Also don't use a form submit button as a general purpose button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<html>
    <body>
    
    <h1>Add comment below</h1>
    
        
        <label for="vname">Comment:</label>
        <input type="text" id="vname" name="vname">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="addComment()">
        
        <ul id="comments"></ul>
      
        <script>
        function addComment()
            {
              var vname = document.getElementById("vname").value;
              var li = document.createElement('li');
              li.innerText = vname;
              document.getElementById('comments').appendChild(li);
              document.getElementById("vname").value = '';
              document.getElementById("vname").focus();
            }
         </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much !! It works fine ! Thank you !